# c# - HttpWebResponse output shows as symbol in messagebox

Tags: c#, json, httpwebresponse

I'm currently trying to receive a response from a `HttpWebRequest` and show it using a MessageBox. I receive the response as fiddler shows but it shows as a symbol in the MessageBox.

**My problem:**

I'm trying to show the response using the `MessageBox.Show` function but the response shows as a symbol. I believe this is caused because the response is a json object.

Screenshot containing response result and fiddler request: [Screenshot link.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eOKZq.png)

**What have I tried:**

I've installed the `Newtonsoft.Json` Nuget packet and tried using it in the following way:

```
var json = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(new StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream()).ReadToEnd());
MessageBox.Show(json.ToString());
```

**C# code to receive the response:**

```
try
{
    string post = "{\"input01\":{\"Input\":\"GmailAddress\",\"GmailAddress\":\"" + words[0] + "\",\"FirstName\":\"\",\"LastName\":\"\"},\"Locale\":\"de\"}";

    HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("https://accounts.google.com/InputValidator?resource=SignUp&service=mail");
    request.Method = "POST";
    request.Accept = "*/*";
    request.Headers.Add("Accept-Encoding", "gzip, deflate, br");
    request.Headers.Add("Accept-Language", "en-US,en;q=0.8");
    request.Host = "accounts.google.com";
    request.UserAgent = "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/51.0.2704.103 Safari/537.36";
    request.ContentType = "application/json";
    request.KeepAlive = true;

    byte[] postBytes = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(post);
    request.ContentLength = postBytes.Length;
    Stream requestStream = request.GetRequestStream();

    requestStream.Write(postBytes, 0, postBytes.Length);
    requestStream.Close();

    HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();

    var html = new StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream()).ReadToEnd();
    MessageBox.Show(html);
}
catch(Exception ex)
{
    MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to get string for JSON object. You should store a different string for this scenario.

```
string resp = new StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream()).ReadToEnd();
var json = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(resp);
MessageBox.Show(resp);
```

Comment: This would cause a Exception: Unexpected charackter encountered while parsing value: . Path ", line 0, position 0.

Comment: @stackjjs, can you try this: `JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<dynamic>(resp);`